# NoSuchFileException in Files.newInputStream with StandardOpenOption.CREATE

Tags: java, nio

I am trying to open a file for reading or create the file if it was not there.
I use this code:

```
String location = "/test1/test2/test3/";
new File(location).mkdirs();
location += "fileName.properties";
Path confDir = Paths.get(location);
InputStream in = Files.newInputStream(confDir, StandardOpenOption.CREATE);
in.close();
```

And I get `java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException`

Considering that I am using `StandardOpenOption.CREATE` option, the file should be created if it is not there.

Any idea why I am getting this exception?

Comment: It doesn't make a lot of sense to create an empty file just for reading.

Comment: in other words, the `CREATE` option is being ignored - by javadoc only the `READ` option must be considered (and is default), other options MAY be supported (implementation specific)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you want one of two quite separate things to happen:

1. If the file exists, read it; or
2. If the file does not exist, create it.

The two things are mutually exclusive but you seem to have confusingly merged them. If the file did not exist and you've just created it, there's no point in reading it. So keep the two things separate:

```
    Path confDir = Paths.get("/test1/test2/test3");
    Files.createDirectories(confDir);
    Path confFile = confDir.resolve("filename.properties");

    if (Files.exists(confFile))
        try (InputStream in = Files.newInputStream(confFile)) {
            // Use the InputStream...
        }
    else
        Files.createFile(confFile);
```

Notice also that it's better to use "try-with-resources" instead of manually closing the InputStream.

Comment: I like your solution. I just do not understand your final notice: "t it's better to use "try-with-resources" instead of manually closing the InputStream". Could you please explain it

Comment: I searched on internet and I got it. Nice feature of Java 7. Thanks

Comment: This answer doesn't answer your question, but helps you to improve your code instead, ignoring the causes of the problem you were dealing with. @Arashsoft

Comment: @Roizpi, I think this post exactly answer my question. Other answers have this assumption that I want to write something in the file. That is a wrong assumption. I want to read the file and if file was not there, just create an empty file there. I have nothing to do with `OutputStream`

Comment: Your question is: "Why do I get NoSuchFileException using StandardOpenOption.CREATE option". There's nothing to misunderstand. In addition everyone since the first comment on your post is suggesting you to check basics at Oracle to improve the code. That is offtopic in my opinion. All right.

Comment: @Roizpi, you are right, the best answer is Carlos Heuberger comment which mentions `CREATE` option for `InputStream` is *implementation specific*. But this answer suggests the best alternative.

Comment: Whatever. Next user coming by this topic, will be because of your question and the given error, not because of the ugliness of the code, as there are many applicable solutions. Whatever is the best answer it is regardless of the correctness of your code, as you did not request it. Suggestions are very important, that is why there is a `Vote-Up` button. Good luck and happy learnings.

Answer (score 2):

Accordingly to the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) you should have used `newOutputStream()` method instead, and then you will create the file:

```java
OutputStream out = Files.newOutputStream(confDir, StandardOpenOption.CREATE);
out.close();
```

JavaDocs:

```
// Opens a file, returning an input stream to read from the file.
static InputStream newInputStream(Path path, OpenOption... options)

// Opens or creates a file, returning an output stream that
// may be used to write bytes to the file.
static OutputStream newOutputStream(Path path, OpenOption... options)
```

The explanation is that `OpenOption` constants usage relies on wether you are going to use it within a write(output) stream or a read(input) stream. This explains why `OpenOption.CREATE` only works deliberatery with the `OutputStream` but not with `InputStream`.

NOTE: I agree with @EJP, you should take a look to [Oracle's tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html) to create files properly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you intended to create an `OutputStream` (for writing to) instead of an `InputStream` (which is for reading)

Another handy way of creating an empty file is using [`apache-commons` `FileUtils`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#touch(java.io.File)) like this

```
FileUtils.touch(new File("/test1/test2/test3/fileName.properties"));
```

Comment: why not use standard Java 7 `Files.createFile(Path)`?